# Вывести все вложенные элементы массива с помощью for

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вывести например все элементы even

```
var arr =[
    even =  [
        {
            d0 : "monday"
            d1 : "tuesday"
            d2 : "wednesday"
            d3 : "saturday"
        }
    ],
    odd =  [
        {
            d : "tuesday"
        }
    ]
]
```

я так понимаю нужен двойной for

Comment: В массиве `even` у вас один элемент - хеш. Причем - с четырьмя одинаковыми ключами `d`. Как js вообще воспримет такой хеш?

Comment: это пример, я не поменял, в программе у меня разные

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев. запишет последний

Answer (score 0):

Переписал ваш пример на языке JavaScript.

```js
var arr = {
 even: {
  d0: "monday",
  d1: "tuesday",
  d2: "wednesday",
  d3: "saturday"
 },
 odd: {
  d: "tuesday"
 }
};


for (var key in arr.even) {
 if (arr.even.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
  console.log(arr.even[key]);
 }
};
```

Или же так, если всё-таки вам приходится работать с приведённой выше структурой данных:

```js
var arr = {
 even: [{
  d0: "monday",
  d1: "tuesday",
  d2: "wednesday",
  d3: "saturday"
 }],
 odd: [{
  d: "tuesday"
 }]
};

arr.even.forEach(function (element) {
 for (var key in element) {
  if (element.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   console.log(element[key]);
  }
 }
});
```